# Choosing highest occuring value from python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tree, nested

I have following sample data:

```
myTypeDict = {
              'ssf': ['ssf', 'short film', 'film','artwork', 'creative work', 'entity'],
              'short film': ['short film', 'film', 'artwork', 'creative work', 'work', 'entity'],
              'silent film': ['silent film', 'film', 'artwork', 'creative work', 'work', 'entity'],
              'island': ['island', 'landform', 'landscape', 'pysio-geographical object', 'geographical object', 'entity'],
              'peninsula': ['peninsula', 'landform', 'landscape', 'pysio-geographical object', 'geographical object', 'entity'],
            }
```

Values in this dictionary are actually ancestors of the key. For each key, I have 5 ancestors. I want to have another dictionary containing this same key, and value as the parent with the highest occurances among all key. E.g. I want output as:

```
{
    'ssf': film,
    'short film': film,
    'silent film': film,
    'island': landform,
    'peninsula': landform
}
```

Since, the film is occurring 3 times in complete dictionary, I will substitute this as parent for `'ssf', 'short film', 'silent film'` etc. Moreover, I need the earliest parent. i.e. even `creative work` is also occurring 3 times, but it is ancestor of `film`. So if the two ancestors occurring same number of times, then I need the earliest one i.e. here 'film'. Similarly for island and peninsula, I need landform. I also can somehow get descendants of each key in nested dictionary format. For this I have following code:

```
myPredicate= URIRef("http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf")
    roots = set()
    mapping = {}
    parents = {} #to store parents
    count = 0
    for s,p,o in g:
        if(p==myPredicate):
            count = count+1
            s = URIRef(s).n3().replace('<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/',"")
            child = s.replace('>',"")
            o = URIRef(o).n3().replace('<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/',"")
            parent = o.replace('>',"")
            parents[child] = parent #populate parents       
            childitem = mapping.get(child,None)
            if childitem is None:
                childitem =  {}
                mapping[child] = childitem
            else:
                roots.discard(child)
            parentitem = mapping.get(parent,None)
            if parentitem is None:
                mapping[parent] = {child:childitem}
                roots.add(parent)
            else:
                parentitem[child] = childitem
```

The dictionary 'mapping' is actually tree. So when I say mapping[key], it gives me subtree rooted as node 'key'. If I could count this nodes in subtree then it'll resolve my issue I guess. Anyone knows how can I count keys in nested dictionary.

Comment: It seems to me that the straightforward way is to simply count all the items in the list-values for your dict, (using a `collections.Counter` or a `dict`) then use that to find the `max` of the children based on that counter.

Comment: I am not sure, whether it will resolve my issue. What in case of two parents having same count?

Comment: If by "earliest ancestor" you mean the first to occur in your list, then `max` should take the first occuring one anyway. Am I missing something?

Comment: okay. I am trying to implement it. I will see and let you know if it works. I haven't used collections.Counter before, so need to check it!

Comment: It is convenient, but it essentially just creates a dictionary of counts, which is pretty trivial to do with a regular dictionary.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide code snippet? I am not getting how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Make a mapping of ancestors to counts, and use that as a key to `max`, so:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(ancestors, width=300)
{'island': ['island', 'landform', 'landscape', 'pysio-geographical object', 'geographical object'],
 'peninsula': ['peninsula', 'landform', 'landscape', 'pysio-geographical object', 'geographical object'],
 'short film': ['short film', 'film', 'artwork', 'creative work', 'work'],
 'silent film': ['silent film', 'film', 'artwork', 'creative work', 'work'],
 'ssf': ['ssf', 'short film', 'film', 'artwork', 'creative work']}
```

Now, use a `collections.Counter`, or just implement this with a regular `dict` if you want:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter(v for vals in ancestors.values() for v in vals)
>>> counts
Counter({'film': 3, 'creative work': 3, 'artwork': 3, 'landform': 2, 'pysio-geographical object': 2, 'geographical object': 2, 'work': 2, 'landscape': 2, 'short film': 2, 'silent film': 1, 'island': 1, 'ssf': 1, 'peninsula': 1})
```

Now, finally, create your new, desired dictionary:

```
>>> final = {k:max(v, key=counts.get) for k, v in ancestors.items()}
>>> pprint(final)
{'island': 'landform',
 'peninsula': 'landform',
 'short film': 'film',
 'silent film': 'film',
 'ssf': 'film'}
```

Note, a `collections.Counter` is just a subclass of `dict` except the constructor takes an iterable of items that it counts for you automatically, but you could have done:

```
>>> counts = {}
>>> for vals in ancestors.values():
...     for v in vals:
...         if v in counts:
...             counts[v] += 1
...         else:
...             counts[v] = 1
...
>>> counts
{'landform': 2, 'silent film': 1, 'pysio-geographical object': 2, 'geographical object': 2, 'island': 1, 'ssf': 1, 'work': 2, 'film': 3, 'landscape': 2, 'short film': 2, 'peninsula': 1, 'creative work': 3, 'artwork': 3}
```

Comment: @NilakshiNaphade yeah, if you are still curious about `Counter` objects, check my edit. Not only do they have a useful constructor, but they also support the `+` and `-` operators between `Counter` objects, that do just what you would hope. They are essentially `dict` objects specialized for counting.

Comment: It's somehow failing on real data. I have explained my problem by editing sample data and above question

Comment: The problem is, with the changed sample data , I am getting 'entity' as parent for all the types. i.e. parent for short film and even island is same i.e. 'entity'. So using max is not a good idea. I somehow need 'film' and 'landform' in above cases.

Comment: @NilakshiNaphade why "somehow" exactly? Your criteria is the "the highest occurances among all key." Entity occurs 5 times, why is it not chosen over the others?

Comment: I needed the earliest parent as well. 'entity' is very general. So everything comes under entity which will not work for me.